# Why are wrong titles shown sometimes?

Tags: bug, questions, title, top-network-posts

I was on the profile of [affable geek](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/1039/affable-geek) and there I saw this question in his "Top Network Post"-list:

(NSFW language used)

> [image]

But this "question" on the history-stackexchange-side resolves to be [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/1579/how-did-the-us-and-uk-gain-diplomatic-relations-in-the-late-1800s-and-early-190), and that title was never actuallly in use (not even for one minute).

The innapropriate eddit got removed, but still...

Why is this title shown?

Comment: That title was from a [previous revision](https://history.stackexchange.com/posts/1579/revisions) (where somebody messed up and approved a very bad edit).

Comment: Nevertheless, why is this wrong title still shown in the list?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @Laurel not really, the change was never alive since it was "approve and edit", and the edit removed that bad title. This is some odd bug.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I wonder if the fact that the two title edits have the same timestamp might have something to do with it. Not sure why that should matter, but I guess there might be some query that is incorrectly sorting post history only by the timestamp, or some cache that's only checking the timestamp to see if it needs to be refreshed.

Comment: Anyway, it looks like a mod purged the inappropriate title from the edit history just recently, which may have stopped this bug from occurring for this question.

Comment: Elijah seems like a pretty cool dude

Comment: @IlmariKaronen is the old "NSFW" title still available? so could the title potentially be activated again?

Comment: If you want to see it again for some reason, it's still visible in the [edit suggestion](https://history.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/31532) that was mistakenly approved. But as far as the actual edit history of the question is concerned, it's as if that approval never happened. I don't think there's any way for the vandalized title to get back into the question (unless, of course, somebody vandalizes it again).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I have a solid guess about what happened, if I'll be able to reproduce I'll edit the bug report here. Also, I'm pretty sure that ordinary edit would have also cleared the bad title from top network posts, though not from the question revisions, so guess redacting it is best course of action. :)